# How to access a file outside the folder of the current file in Node JS

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, electron, fs

Hi so I want to use child_process to run a python file from JavaScript file but that python file is outside the folder where my JavaScript file is located is there some way to pinpoint a file that is outside the folder that I'm currently in because I tried `const process = spawn('python', ../cloud.py)` but that does not seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have below folder structure:

cloud.py

folder2

- js file

then you have to come out of js folder and thne can access python file as below

```
const process = spawn('python', ./../cloud.py)
```

Comment: This also did not seem to work I don't know if maybe I'm doing somthing wrong.

Comment: @RodanyAntoine try `const process = spawn('python', ../cloud.py)`  Again this depends on your folder structure. if you folder structure is same as i gave in example, then it must work